# How to make a simple countdown in minutes for swift iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, timer

How do I code a simple timer countdown from MINUTES say for example 5 minute countdown?

Like the timer that apple created. Is there a way to download and see the xcode project for apple apps?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site isn't really well suited to "How do I do XYZ" type questions. It's intended for people asking for help with code they've written. As for downloading the Xcode project for Apple's apps, the answer is "of course not." Why would Apple publish the secrets to the software that they use to distinguish their products from the competition?

Answer (score 25):

Look into NSTimer as a simple way to do this.  May not be the most accurate but is relatively simple.  The NSTimer calls the function "update" every second (indicated by the 1.0 as the first argument)

```
@IBOutlet var countDownLabel: UILabel!

var count = 300

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("update"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func update() {

    if(count > 0){
        let minutes = String(count / 60)
        let seconds = String(count % 60)
        countDownLabel.text = minutes + ":" + seconds
        count--
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you that solved my issue