# Button text flashes when title is set using a timer function, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uilabel

I am following the answer shown here in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34821687/2534233) to implement a countdown timer. The timer text does not flash (works perfectly) when the text is set for a label.

When the same text is set for a button it flashes every time the title is set. How can avoid the button text flashing ?

```
@IBOutlet weak var countDownTimer: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var countDownTimerButton: UIButton!
var count = 120

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


func update() {

    if(count > 0){
        let minutes = String(count / 60)
        let seconds = String(count % 60)
        countDownTimer.text = minutes + ":" + seconds // Setting text for label (Works perfectly)

        let text = minutes + ":" + seconds
        countDownTimerButton.setTitle(text, for: .normal) // Setting text for button, (Text flashes everytime it is set)
        count -= 1
    }

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is caused through the setting of the button title text. Just set the type of the button to custom and the flashing should stop

Comment: It works but did not understand the reason behind it. How does setting button type to custom resolves the issue?

Comment: It works. My button is in UItableview and whenever I scroll it and button title will change according to the position. and the annoying part is it flashes while changing the title. I puzzled it stopped flashing when I set to type custom. Even I don't know the logic behind it.

Answer (score 0):

flashes because it gets hit everytime you `-1` try this one

```
    @IBOutlet weak var countDownTimer: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var countDownTimerButton: UIButton!
var count = 120

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


func update() {

    if(count > 0){
        let minutes = String(count / 60)
        let seconds = String(count % 60)
        countDownTimer.text = minutes + ":" + seconds // Setting text for label (Works perfectly)

        let text = minutes + ":" + seconds

        count -= 1
    }
countDownTimerButton.setTitle(text, for: .normal) // Setting text for button, (Text flashes everytime it is set)

}
```